# Java Choice Selected Index not returning properly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, selection

Ok, so here is the problem: Every time I click OK it should return the selected index number, right? The code below is returning ONLY the first index regardless of what I select. I set "cMenu.selected(1)" and it returns index 1, again, regardless of what I select.

Using JPanel, JButton, Choice

```
String[] menu = {"item 1" , "item 2", "item3"};

cMenu = new Choice();
cMenu.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 25);
for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++)
    cMenu.add(menu[i]);
}
panel.add(cMenu);

final int menuSelection = cMenu.getSelectedIndex();

//Below is, of course, debugging
//Before asking, the button works it does say 0 or Hello World or whatever I want
//when clicked

OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(menuSelection);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recalculate the value for `menuSelection` when the 'OK' button is clicked; you're setting it once during instantiation of the `Choice` as shown below:

```
final int menuSelection = cMenu.getSelectedIndex();
```

If you do something like this, you should be able to see your value:

```
OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int currentSelection = cMenu.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println(currentSelection);
    }
});
```

This will mean `cMenu` should be final, which is probably OK because you don't need to ever update that reference.

Comment: WHOOPS! I had to edit the code a little before posting it. i forgot to change cClass to cMenu before I posted it here! I'm changing it now

Comment: On the same subject, how could i get the selection to dynamically change content(JLabel)? say if item1 was selected the list will show (in the gui) List: bread, milk, ect; or if selected item2 List: eggs, butter, ect

Comment: @SilverWolfe In that `actionPerformed` method, you can run any code you want.  You could do `if(currentSelection == 2) { // Update the Jpanel's components }`.  That might be better suited for another question though, as I'm not the best resource for dynamically a GUI with AWT.

Comment: Thanks for your input! This code worked for me. It might be easier for me to put all this in a method and then call it in actionPerformed

Answer (score 1):

"OK it should return the selected index number". No, it should not. you're calling getSelectedIndex() once. So your int has the same value forever. You have to call getSelectedIndex() in your listener to get the new value.